# .NET 6 IoC register services from another assembly

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, inversion-of-control

I'd like to register some services from another assembly with built-in IoC of .NET 6. Is it possible as Autofac does?

I found others nuget extensions, still not sure what it is the best practice

Thanks

Comment: You can just use Autofac in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @GuruStron I'd like avoiding to use Autoface since there is the built-in which works, is it the only option in your opinion?

Comment: Autofac is great mature DI container. If you need features which are not provided via build-in one - you can absolutely use [another one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement).

Comment: Another option is to use assembly scanning library like [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor)

Comment: @GuruStron agree, just installed Scruton and looking for the correct extension I really need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Scrutor is the way*. Just tried this example

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"path\stuff.dll");

builder.Services.Scan(scan => scan.FromAssemblies(assembly)
            .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IMyInterface>())
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .WithScopedLifetime());
```

It works, easier. Fantastic!